# SolrJ and Custom Solr Handler

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to implement a simple custom request handler in Solr 7.3. I needed some clarifications on the methods available via the Solr Java API.

As per my understanding, I have extended my Java Class with "SearchHandler" and then overridden the "handleRequestBody" method. I am trying to understand the flow from the beginning. Here is a sample query in the browser.

```
    http://localhost:8983/solr/customcollection/customhandler? 
    q=John&fl=id,last_name&maxRows=10
```

````
1) Once you enter the above query in the browser and press 
"return" the Solr customhandler will be triggered. It will look 
for the necessary jars from where the handler is created.

2) Once it finds the main class it will execute the following 
method, which is overridden from the "SearchHandler" parent 
class.
        public void handleRequestBody(SolrRequest req, SolrResponse 
        resp) throws Exception

3) The SolrRequest req object will hold all the Solr Parameters 
on the query, in this case, q,fl and maxRows.

4) Using the following code I unpack these parameters.

        SolrParams params = req.getParams();
        String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
        String fl = params.getParams(CommonParams.FL);
        String rows = params.get(CommonParams.ROWS);

5)I create a Solr object that let's me connect to my Solr Cloud
        String zkHostString = "localhost:5181";
        SolrClient solr = new 
        CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHostString).build();

6) Here is where I need help
            a) How do I use the unpacked Solr Parameters from the 
            original query and make a call to the "solr" object to 
            return results.
            b) How do I make use of the "resp" object?
            c) Most of the examples that I found on the internet show 
            how to print the results to STDOUT. However, since I am 
            using a custom handler I would like to display the results 
            back to the user (in this case, SOLR Admin or the browser).```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks

        public class SolrQueryTest extends 
        org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler {

    String zkHostString = "localhost:5181";
    SolrClient solr = new 
        CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHostString).build();

    private static final Logger log = 
        Logger.getLogger(SolrQueryTest.class.getName());


    public void handleRequestBody(SolrRequest req, SolrResponse 
        resp) throws Exception {

        SolrParams params = req.getParams();
    String q = params.get(CommonParams.Q);
    String rows = params.get(CommonParams.ROWS);

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(q);
    query.setShowDebugInfo(true);
    query.set("indent", "true");
    // need to know how to call SOLR using the above query 
        parameters
    //Once the response is received how to send it back to the 
        browser and NOT STDOUT


    }
}
````

Comment: Why do you want write your own request handler? And, in any case, I strongly discourage to use SolrJ there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Why wouldn't you create a custom handler if the default handlers do not suffice?

Comment: Please answer my question first.

Comment: I am interested in creating my own type ahead search. I have some business logic to implement before I start responding to the type ahead queries. The suggested provided by solr out of the box is bare bore minimum and doesn't meef my requirements. This type ahead will ensure that correct elements are searched ( in a pre defined order) to generate a proper response.

Comment: Instead of embed such behavior in a customized handler why don’t write simply a web app that calls Solr.

Comment: Writing a custom handler is usually needed when you want slightly modify a standard behavior, but takes many difficulties. Consider the hassles of debugging your code directly into Solr, or during the  deployment of every update (your code and your data are in the same place) your Solr instance needs to be offline or unreachable until your deployment has completed.